# How to get population based on lat and long of any location in google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, population

Is there any API to get population based on lat and long of any location?  I searched so many times but till now I never get. Please help in this if you know any API which will provide population based on location.

Comment: You'll need to define your requirements more clearly with regard to the location.  The nearest city to the location?  The country the location is in?  An exact location can only have a population of zero or one...

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Not true.  Someone could stand on someone else's shoulders.

Comment: @ajb Android locations include altitude. :)  Though granted the OP did specify lat and long.

Comment: @ Kevin Krumwiede .. I need when i open google map and choose one area inside the city... based on that area latitude and longitude i need to get population with in the 10km or 5km radious around my location that what i am looking for...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **Factual's GeoPulse Context API**  http://www.programmableweb.com/api/factual-geopulse-context .Take a look.

Comment: thanks Xeqtr@ .. I need when i open google map and choose one area inside the city... based on that area latitude and longitude i need to get population with in the 10km or 5km radious around my location that what i am looking for...

Comment: Above mentioned API should do the job.